# COD Warzone crashes to desktop (CTD) with no message 5-10 min in game. Any new solution or upcoming fix?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

New MSI GS66 PC with 10th gen i7, latest GTX 2070 with 8GB VRAM, all windows & nvidia updates made. The game is up to date.

Approx 10 min in game, it crashes to desktop with no error message. Has this not been fixed yet? I tried like 2 months ago, had this problem and didn't play since hoping an update will fix it. Now it still crashes.

Tried suggestions that I found here and there that are 3-4 months old but to no avail (such as this: https://www.reddit.com/r/CODWarzone/comments/fm8rfe/my_cod_warzone_keeps_crashing/).

Anyone have a more recent solution to the problem or do you know if an update is on the way to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked EventViewer for any logs?

Comment: Did this start occurring on a fresh install of the game, or has it started randomly happen lately? Perhaps after a patch or update?

Comment: Later patches to the game sometimes fixed it, other times made it crash again.  I suspected it had something to do with shaders.  However I didn't play in a looog while, so don't know if still a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

Go to Settings > Graphics and then in the top right there should be a bar labeled "vRAM".

If the bar is red, it's using too many resources. Adjust your graphics settings a bit until it turns blue.

Comment: It's a powerful machine so no problem with vRAM. It was actually a problem with the game itself, future updates sometimes improved, sometimes worsened the situation.